# Why can't you pass a conditional expression to a Javascript Hash key?

Tags: javascript

Why can't you pass an expression to a Javascript Hash key?

```js
let o = {
  one: 12,
  two: 23,
  three: 90
}

console.log(
  o['foo' || 'one']
)
```

// undefined

Comment: because the check has nothing to do with the value. It is checking for the truthiness of 'foo'

Comment: `o['foo' || 'one']` evaluates to `o['foo']` which is undefined because `o` has no property `foo`. This is because `'foo'` is truthy

Comment: Exactly, 'foo' will always be true but when you search it within its indexes it is undefined for not being previously defined, in that case it would have to have some method of "internal search" of the following index as indicated in my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In here, your code will evaluate `('foo' || 'one') // which is foo` first, and then try to access that property of `o`, which is undefined.

What you probably would like to do is:

```
o['foo'] || o['one']
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code always return null since always look for 'foo' because it is a string with more than one bit and is considered true so it will look for its first position in the object and it will return undefined.

Tienes dos formas de como hacer eso y una es la siguiente:

***This form was shown to you by Alberto Rivera (the first comment)***

```
o['foo'] || o['one']
```

The second option is to have a method to validate that the index exists in the object and return the first position as this example:

```
let o = {
    one: 12,
    two: 23,
    three: 90
}

let validate = a => a.filter(v => v in o)[0]

console.log(
  o[validate(['foo', 'one'])]
);
```

In this last case you will always return the first value that you find in the object but in summary, the way you do it is incorrect since 'foo' will always give true because you are not indicating that look for that within your object.